# Read SQLlite DB from another apps

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to ask about how to read a DB from another app. We already have an app running on the device, but we have another project that refers to the previous DB.

I have dbAdapter.class to read the path to the DB, but I found some errors like "unable to open the database.

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.project.factory.apps/databases/";
private static final String DB_NAME = "dbData.db";
private static String DB_PATH_SDCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/com.project.factory.apps/databases/";
private Context myContext;

public dbAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        myContext = context;
}


public boolean createDatabase(){
    if(DatabaseIsExist()) {
        return false;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean DatabaseIsExist(){
        checkDb = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
             File directory = new File(DB_PATH_SDCARD);
             if(!directory.exists())
                 directory.mkdirs();

             checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.project.factory.apps/databases/dbData.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.e("File not found in data",e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   

    public List<t_listInfo> getList() {
        try {
            dataAdapter = DaoManager.createDao(this.getConnectionSource(), t_listInfo.class);
            return dataAdapter.queryForAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**on MyActivity.Class**

```
db.createDatabase();
db.getReadableDatabase();

data = db.getList();
```

I got an error in call the `getList()` function and need a suggestion or correction if the code was wrong.

Comment: i dont think it is possible

Comment: If there any way besides using ContentProviders? as I know the contectproviders need to change the script from the prev apps right ? because the previous apps develop by another division, we just have access only DB. Can we access by rooting the phone ?? or have another way ?

Comment: even if rooting deveice if u get access  how u will  root ur users device

Comment: just see on this web http://rratmansky.wordpress.com/?p=259&preview=true. Can we use that link ?

Comment: This is designed in this manner for this exact reason.  Why should you get data to an app that is not yours or the author has not exposed.  If this app is 'truly' yours then you will need to update the application to expose the data, or store the data centrally on a server and access the data from both applications.  As @Shakeeb has said, yes with a rooted device you could gain access, will all of the devices you will be running on be rooted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  You should look into [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), this will allow you to access the data from other applications, using a syntax that allows you to query and specify the data you want.